# Bootstrap space between composent and text inside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've got some problem with my bootstrap:

[image: demo]

I would like to have a small blank between the squares and all the text to be on each square.

Some text are too long and I'm wondering how to have them appear with some "..." at the end.

I've tried to play with the css but I don't succeed.

This is the component corresponding to a square (document-detail component):

```
<div *ngIf="document" (click)="onSelect()" class="document">
    <div>
        <label> <b>{{getName()}}</b> </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div *ngIf="document.date">
        <label> <b> Date: </b> </label> {{document.date}}
    </div>
    <span [ngClass]="{'glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign': selected === false,
    'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign': selected === true}" ></span>
</div>
```

For all the squares to be the same size I used a css:

```
.document{
    height: 9em;
}
```

But I don't know if it's the best solution.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

This is the html file which generate all the webpage:

```
<div class=container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
      <div [ngClass] ="{'alert alert-success': status === 'ElasticSearch Server is working !',
            'alert alert-danger': status === 'ElasticSearch Server is down !',
             'alert-dismissible': 'true',
             'fade in': 'true'}" data-dismiss="alert">
            <strong>{{status}}</strong> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <ul class="list-inline col-md-offset-2 col-md-5 col-md-offset-2" >
    <h5> <strong> Parameters:  </strong></h5>
      <li *ngIf="displayedSearchParams?.length < 1"> No parameters
      <li class="list-group-item parameters" *ngFor="let param of displayedSearchParams" >{{ param }} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" (click)="onDelete(param)"></span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div> 

<div class="row">
  <form class="form-group col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    <ng2-completer placeholder="Search..." class="input-sm form-control col-md-3" [(ngModel)]="searchStr" [datasource]="options" [minSearchLength]="1" 
      (keyup)="search($event, this.ControlSearch)" 
[formControl]="ControlSearch"></ng2-completer>


    <ng2-completer placeholder="Country, region, city,..." class="input-sm form-control col-md-2" [(ngModel)]="searchCity" [datasource]="cities" [minSearchLength]="3" 
      (keyup)="search($event, this.ControlCity)" 
[formControl]="ControlCity"></ng2-completer>

    <label class="checkbox-inline text-center"><input type="checkbox" 
[formControl]="ControlCSV" (click)="onClickCSV()">CSV</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline text-center"><input type="checkbox" 
[formControl]="ControlPictures" (click)="onClickPictures()">Pictures</label>

  </form>
</div>


<div *ngIf="documentSources" class="row">
  <app-documentlist [documentSources]="documentSources"></app-documentlist>
</div>
```

And here the html file of document-liste Component:

```
<div class="row">
 <div *ngFor="let documentSource of documentSources" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <app-document-details [document]="documentSource._source"> </app-document-details>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div *ngIf="documentSources?.length < 1" class="alert alert-warning col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
  <p>No files found! {{documentSources}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the css I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and a small CSS:

```
.completer-input{
    display: inherit;
    width: 58em;
    border : none;
}

.completer-selected-row {
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 20em;
}

.col-height{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 0.2em
}

.parameters{
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 0.1em;
}

.document{
    height: 9em;
    border: 4em;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is your table structure? Are you using the Bootstrap grid layout because I dont see classes from that being used here? What is your CSS? Are you using `margin` and `padding`, have you tried `overflow: hidden` on your containers?

Comment: I've added more informations in my description